# How to use containsKey in a case insensitive way using Gson?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a string of JSON that I use Gson to convert to JSON Object. However, I'd like to use `containsKey` as a case insensitive way.

Here's what I'm doing right now.

```
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(payload);
    String data = forName("UTF-8").newDecoder().decode(buffer).toString();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Map<String, String> map = gson.fromJson(data, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
    }.getType());
```

And then I have this method `isTupleValid` to check if the tuple is valid.

```
private boolean isTupleValid(Map<String, String> map) {
    return map != null && map.containsKey(TYPE)
            && map.containsKey(XID)
            && map.containsKey(CTP)
            && map.get(TYPE).equals("pageview");
}
```

However, sometimes the json string could be

`{"xid": "xid"}` or it can be `{"xID":"xid"}`

Is there a way to use `containsKey` in a case sensitive way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092710/how-to-check-for-key-in-a-map-irrespective-of-the-case

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work in Gson case.
          Map<String, String> mapClass = new TreeMap<>(INSTANCE);
            Map<String, String> map = gson.fromJson(data, mapClass.getClass());

Comment: hmm that INSTANCE looks rather weird to me but can you try this: Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

Comment: I tried this 
            Map<String, String> mapClass = new TreeMap<>(CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
            Map<String, String> map = gson.fromJson(data, mapClass.getClass());
Still doesn't work.

Comment: can you do some debug and check out what is exactly going wrong?

Comment: I did some debugging. I can see that GSON converts to TreeMap. However, when I use `containsKey`. It has to be exact match.

Answer (score 0):

`gson.fromJson(data, new TreeMap<>(...).getClass())` does not make much sense since `getClass()` only returns the object class, and not its internal state -- simply speaking, you always get `TreeMap.class` regardless the arguments passed to the `TreeMap` constructor.

To me, there are two options. They two use "normalized" maps and have their own advantages and disadvantages.

First off, let's create the commons class in order to share the basics between two approaches demos:

### Commons.java

```java
final class Commons {

    private Commons() {
    }

    static final String CTP = "ctp";
    static final String TYPE = "type";
    static final String XID = "xid";

    static final String JSON_1 = "{\"xid\":\"foo\",\"type\":\"pageview\",\"ctp\":\"ctp\"}";
    static final String JSON_2 = "{\"xID\":\"foo\",\"tYPE\":\"pageview\",\"cTP\":\"ctp\"}";

    static Map<String, Object> normalizeMap(final Map<String, Object> map) {
        final Map<String, Object> normalized = new TreeMap<>(CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        normalized.putAll(map);
        return normalized;
    }

}
```

### CaseInsensitive1.java

This option does not touch the original deserialization strategy, so the consuming code must check against case-insensitivity itself. It's necessary to put the "map normalization" code where it makes sense. Note that the original map remains unchanged.

```java
public final class CaseInsensitive1 {

    private CaseInsensitive1() {
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final Gson gson = new Gson();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final Map<String, Object> map1 = gson.fromJson(JSON_1, Map.class);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final Map<String, Object> map2 = gson.fromJson(JSON_2, Map.class);
        out.println(isTupleValid(map1));
        out.println(isTupleValid(map2));
    }

    private static boolean isTupleValid(final Map<String, Object> map) {
        if ( map == null ) {
            return false;
        }
        final Map<String, Object> ciMap = normalizeMap(map);
        return ciMap.containsKey(TYPE)
                && ciMap.containsKey(XID)
                && ciMap.containsKey(CTP)
                && ciMap.get(TYPE).equals("pageview");
    }

}
```

### CaseInsensitive2.java

This option creates a special GSON instance that deserializes `Map<String, Object>` in a "normalized" way. Note that `mapStringObjectType` is used everywhere since I mapped the deserialization strategy for that concrete type. It might be mapped just to `Map.class` of course. The `decorateGson` takes another GSON instance in order to "inherit" the previosly built behavior you might need. Despite the `isTupleValid` method is now equivalent to yours, a disadvantage of this option is that you lose the properties order of the original JSON object. However, you might want to use [case-insensitive maps not based on TreeMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813358/appropriately-backing-a-case-insensitive-map) (not sure, but it could make the map behave in case-insensitive way keeping the original properties order).

```java
public final class CaseInsensitive2 {

    private CaseInsensitive2() {
    }

    private static final Type mapStringObjectType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {
    }.getType();

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final Gson originalGson = new Gson();
        final Gson gson = decorateGson(originalGson);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final Map<String, Object> map1 = gson.fromJson(JSON_1, mapStringObjectType);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final Map<String, Object> map2 = gson.fromJson(JSON_2, mapStringObjectType);
        out.println(isTupleValid(map1));
        out.println(isTupleValid(map2));
    }

    private static boolean isTupleValid(final Map<String, Object> map) {
        return map != null
                && map.containsKey(TYPE)
                && map.containsKey(XID)
                && map.containsKey(CTP)
                && map.get(TYPE).equals("pageview");
    }

    private static Gson decorateGson(final Gson originalGson) {
        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
        final TypeAdapter<Map<String, Object>> adapter = (TypeAdapter) originalGson.getAdapter(Map.class);
        final JsonDeserializer<Map<String, Object>> typeAdapter = (json, type, context) -> normalizeMap(adapter.fromJsonTree(json));
        return new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(mapStringObjectType, typeAdapter)
                .create();
    }

}
```

To me, the option #1 looks better, since it does not decorate the originally deserialized object in any way (what if I need it to be case-sensitive later in the code?) and the case-insensitive check is performed only *when it's really needed*.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to check if the key exist without retrieving the value. You could access the `keySet`. Stream over it and call `anyMatch` with an `ignoreCase` predicate. In your case :

```
return ciMap.keySet().stream().anyMatch(key -> key.equalsIgnoreCase(TYPE))
                && ciMap.keySet().stream().anyMatch(key -> key.equalsIgnoreCase(XID))
                && ciMap.keySet().stream().anyMatch(key -> key.equalsIgnoreCase(CTP))
                && ciMap.get(TYPE).equals("pageview");
```

**PS : You may consider using an appropriate data structure. The keys in this case could not be equal and nevertheless return true. This violates the Map contract.**